# Question regarding SQL optimzation

Tags: sql, database

This might be a silly question but i just want to make this clear. Does it take longer to preform a SQL query if each row has a large amount of data inside of it?

For instance if i've like 2000 bytes worth of data stored as an blob (we call the colum "Data") in a row of a table containing 10 000 rows as a total (all of them similar with the blob size of "Data") . Will it then take longer to process of an search if i only search for the ID for one row e.g does the server have to like process the whole information stored in each colum of every row it passes by?

Comment: Look at Justin's answer, he actually answered your question.  Searching for the ID goes through the index on the ID column, and goes just as fast no matter how many columns in the table or what types they are.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general if your ID column is the primary key on the table (or at least has an index) then a simple query like

```
SELECT ID,Data FROM Table WHERE ID = 1
```

will be just as fast no matter the size of the Data column

Comment: The size of the data column does make a difference I'd say as it needs to be sent over the network to the client. So the larger the data column, the longer sending of the result will take.

Comment: Spot on a_horse_with_no_name, I had originally written 'provided the data isn't returned to the client" but then ammended the SQL to a more useful example that did return the Data column. My bad.

Comment: ...but... Returning a single row with say 2k will have *very little* impact on overall time and *extremely little* impact on time to process the request.

Answer (score 4):

This depends on the engine you are using.

However, most modern engines are able to store the long data out of row: the actual row tables which need to be scanned in searching only store the pointer to the actual chunk(s) of long data.

Also, if you have an index on `id` in a heap table, the index will be used for the search. The index records only store the values of `id` and the record pointer. Even if the table is clustered (the records themselves are ordered by `id`), then the `B-Tree` search algorithm will be used to locate the record you're after, only processing the actual records in the final leaf-level page.

So most probably, the long data will not be scanned if you search for id.

If your data are stored in-row and no index is defined on the expression you are searching for, then yes, the engine needs to scan more records which will be more slow if they are large.

Answer (score 1):

> Does it take longer to preform a SQL query if each row has a large amount of data inside of it?

On paper, yes. Disk page reads then contain less rows, so you need more IO to extract the rows you're looking for.

In practice, the overhead can be tiny depending on how your database stores its contents. PostgreSQL, for instance, distinguishes between plain vs extended storage for data with variable length such as lengthy varchar, text or bytea.

Answer (score 0):

In general, there are 2 things that will determine the speed of your query:

- how long does it take to find the record(s) specified? If you're searching by ID, the things Quassnoi and Justin have said are true - assuming your ID is a primary key with an index associated with it.
- how long does it take for me to retrieve the data associated with this record and push it out of the database? In this case, the data types do matter - and BLOBs have a poorer reputation for performance than "native" data types such as integers or varchars. You also need to factor in the effort of transforming the blob into it's actual type at the client side.

For a single record, this should be a tiny overhead; if you ever need to retrieve large amounts of data, it might be slower.

Your database engine should have detailed documentation on the performance of BLOBs.